# Compactness of the convex envelope in a Banach space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $K$ is a compact subset of a Banach space $E$. Denote the convex hull of $K$ (the smallest convex subset of $E$ containing $K$) by $C(K)$.

Prove that $\overline{C(K)}$ is compact but $C(K)$ is not always compact.

I could neither prove the first part nor the second; in finite dimension, I could prove compactness even without closure.

Could someone please give a hint for this problem?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: I edited your title to make it more descriptive, if you don't mind.

Comment: For the second part, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017113/is-the-convex-hull-of-a-compact-set-compact/2017145#2017145

Comment: @AlexProvost Thanks~ nice improvement~