# Proof verification for some properties of convex hulls

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, convex-analysis, compactness, convex-hulls

> Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $A$ be a subset of $X$. $\operatorname{conv}(A)$
>   is called the intersection of all convex subsets of $X$ that contain
>   $A$
>
> a) Show that $\operatorname{conv}(A)$ is a convex set
>
> b) Show that
>
> $$\operatorname{conv}(A) = \bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda _i x_i : \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i =1,
>  \lambda_i\ge 0, x_i\in A, i=1,\cdots,n\bigg\}$$
>
> c) If $A$ is compact then is $\operatorname{conv}(A)$ compact?
>
> d) Show that if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact then $\operatorname{conv}(A)$ is
>   compact

**a)** Take two elements $a$ and $b$ at the intersection of all convex subsets of $X$ that contain $A$. Now take $\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$. It is contained in every of the subsets of $X$ that contain $A$, therefore it is contained in the intersection. Q.E.D.

**b)**

[$\Leftarrow$]
Suppose by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i $ belongs to $\operatorname{conv}(A)$. We must prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\lambda_i x_i $, with $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}=1$ also belongs.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\lambda_i x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i x_i + \lambda_{k+1}x_{k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i x_i + (1-\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i)x_{k+1}$$

Now choose $\delta$ such that $\delta\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i=1$, then

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i x_i + (1-\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i)x_{k+1}\right)= \left(\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{i=1}^{k}(\delta\lambda_i) x_i + \frac{1}{\delta}(\delta-1)x_{k+1}\right) =\\ \frac{1}{\delta}x + \left(1-\frac{1}{\delta}\right)x_{k+1}$$

which is a combination of elements of $A$ that sums to $1$

[$\Rightarrow$] 
Can I just say that $x\in\operatorname{conv}(A)$, then $x = 1x + 0\cdot everything$ therefore it is a combination that sums to $1$ of elements of $A$?

**c)** A hint is provided: show that $\operatorname{conv}(A\cup B)$ is the image by a continuous function of the compact $\{(\alpha,\beta; \alpha,\beta\ge 0, \alpha + \beta = 1)\}\times A\times B$. I don't understand how to show this.

**d)** Any hints?

Comment: Your part $b$ is correct. For part $c$, recall that the image of a compact set under a continuous function is also compact. I am not sure what part $d$ is asking (i.e it seems the same as part $c$.

Comment: Part b is not correct; you cannot conclude on the basis that $x = 1x$ that $x$ belongs to the proposed convex hull, as $x$ may not belong to $A$. Instead, try proving that the proposed convex hull is convex. If it is, then it is a convex set containing $A$, so if $x$ is not in this set, it must not be in the convex hull of $A$.

Comment: d) is proved in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Comment: An interesting side note on part (d): it does not hold true in more general vector spaces--see [this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017113/is-the-convex-hull-of-a-compact-set-compact).

Comment: @rubikscube09 Part (c) is asking about a general normed vector space $X$, while part (d) is specific to the case $X=\mathbb{R}^n$.