# Convex hull of a compact set in a normed linear space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I want to show that the closure of the convex hull of a compact set in a normed linear space is compact. This came up in a book on Functional Analysis where the author wants to make sense of vector valued integration.

In particular the problem is if $\varphi: [0,1]\rightarrow V$ be a continuous map from the unit interval to a real normed linear space then the closure of the convex hull of $\varphi([0,1])$ is compact. There are questions on stakexchange, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017113/is-the-convex-hull-of-a-compact-set-compact) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214758/how-to-prove-that-the-closed-convex-hull-of-a-compact-subset-of-a-banach-space-i?noredirect=1&lq=1), which deal with similar issues but they do not answer my question.

Comment: Is this true?  I would think you would have to be in a complete normed linear space to expect such closures to be compact

Comment: @D_S, That is exactly what I have been thinking. One of the links provided proves this for Banach spaces.

Comment: Why do you say that the second link does not answer your question? What is your problem with the counter example given there?

Comment: @MoisheCohen, I have an added condition which is absent in that question, which is - ${\textbf{closure}}$ of the convex hull of a compact set.

Comment: [Here](http://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001:1970:16::95) there is a counterexample for an incomplete subspace of $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: @A.G., So does that mean we cannot make sense of vector integration on a normed linear space if it is incomplete. I say this since the author uses this fact to prove that the vector integration of a continuous function $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow V$ exists for a normed linear space $V$.

Comment: @Parish I'm not an expert on incomplete vector spaces, but intuitively completeness is important to define an integral as a limit (contrary to a general approach via the dual space, but then you loose some kind of regularity).

Comment: @Parish: About which book are we talking?

Comment: @PhoemueX, I am talking about the book on Functional Analysis by S. Kesavan. Proposition 3.3.1, Page 83.