# Compact convex sets are "small"

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces, convex-geometry

Let ($E$, $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ ) be a normed vector space and let $C$ be a convex and compact subset of $E$ such that $0 \in C$. I claim $C$ is contained in a finite dimensional subspace of $E$.

To see this, let $V = \text{span} (C)$. Take $x$ in the interior of $V \cap C$ relative to $V$ and a closed ball $B$ centered at $x$  so small that $B' := B \cap V \cap C$ is contained in $V \cap C$. Then $B'$ is a compact ball of $V$, hence $V$ is finite dimensional.

The issue here is: can I guarantee that the interior of $V \cap C$ is nonempty relative to $V$? I think it is geometrically clear, but I couldn't find a proof.

Comment: In a Banach space, the closed convex hull of a compact set is compact. Your statement would imply that (in Banach spaces) that all compact sets are contained in a finite dimensional subspace.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214758/27978, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample to your claim is the [Hilbert cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube), the set of all vectors in $x\in \ell^2$ such that $0\le x_n\le 1/n$ for all $n$. It is compact and convex, but is not contained in any finite-dimensional subspace.

A subset of a Banach space is compact if and only if it is **closed**, **bounded**, and "**flat**", where the latter means: for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite-dimensional subspace $M$ such that the set is contained in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $M$. See  my blog post [Compact sets in Banach spaces](https://calculus7.org/2017/04/27/compact-sets-in-banach-spaces/).